# How to visually display overlapping information

Tags: gui-design, info-visualisation, charts

For example, take the following data, with:
- Recipients 
- Sent Mails
- Opens
- Bounced

I want to show the data like this:

- First whole pie for the reciepents. (100%)
- Sent mail (80%)
- Opens (30%)
- bounced (20%)

**Note**: opens and bounced are the part of the sent slice.

How would it be best to display it graphically.  I've thought of using a pie chart, which you can see below.

[image]

Comment: I'm confused as to how these will fit into a pie chart...

Comment: I am also is there any other way to represent this graphically

Comment: I think you are talking about >1 chart: sent vs bounced, opened vs ignored, etc.

Comment: Perhaps your segments are: bounced, read, ignored, other where the total 'pie' is all sent email.

Comment: @tohster will you please tell me how to migrate this question to appropriate site.

Comment: @tohster, this is not an implementation question. It’s about how to visualize data and suits UX.SE very well.

Comment: @jazzro I think I just don't understand the question. I've deleted the comment accordingly

Comment: @ethrbunny you are absolute right

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're missing data about what users want to see.

Rough guess of what it might be and thing to approach target group with for further feedback and insights of their needs:

1. Some comparsion of recipient groups sizes. Anyhow. Just a number could be enough.
2. See a pie chart for recipients (100%). This would display successfully sent emails (80%) and bounced emails (20%).
3. See open rate. (30%) Number can be enough.

Comment: BTW: Whose dashboard you are designing, if it's not secret?

Comment: I m designing the bulk mail system dashboard i want to show the no of recps, sent mails, opens, and bounced mails in percentage and no. both now i m using the tables to show the data but i want to capture user attention by show the data in graphical format something similar to the pie chart.

Comment: Please see the image in post  for the clarification what i want to do

Comment: I get it. In such case take what you have and show it to people who you design the system for. Plus ask for their terminology. You might hear sth about soft and hard bounces that might help you solving your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Stacked bar charts might also work, especially if you want to visually compare multiple campaigns. But I agree that the labels/values shown in your pie chart might not be helpful to the end users. Some people might consider a bounce a failure. Clarification on the data set will help you determine which chart type is most appropriate.

Comment: will you please tell me which type of chart type is used for show the details of one campaing according to you ?

Comment: You could look at MailChimp's interface, they use line charts to track clicks/opens across time.

Constant Contact combines columns (sent and bounce) with lines for open and click rates.

Answer (score 0):

Use the chart to tell a story, without a story the chart just shows the data that’s already in the table, but then in a less readable way.

I can only make a guess what that story should be, but I assume that it is about telling the difference between the total of emails that were attempted to be sent, the amount of sent/received emails and the ones that got opened/read.

Pie charts are good at showing proportions relatively to the total (the whole pie) but not at comparing proportions against each other.

Therefore I would propose the following bar chart. The bar on the left shows the total attempts. The bar in the middle shows the amount that was successfully sent and also shows how much did bounce. The bar at the right shows how many emails got opened and can be easily compared against the other two bars.

[image]

Note: color can make it difficult for people with color blindness to quickly understand a chart, use it with care.

Comment: will you please tell me sir why are you making another bar for opened we can show it to the sent bar also. sorry but i am developer so have less ux knowledge

Comment: That’s a good question. It’s all about the story you try to tell. In this case I assumed it is more important to tell how many emails got opened against the amount sent. Bounced emails can point out a risk but is still about sent email so I thought it is less important to compare. You can choose not to show bounced email at all or give it it’s own bar (making “opened” even or less important).

Comment: Forgot to mention that it’s easier to compare bars when they are next to each other than when they are stacked on top of each other, obviously.